# How can I fix problem with could not find antlr4 jar file at maven.org?

Tags: maven, antlr, antlr4

I am using Mac OS.
I used command `pip install antlr4-tools` which successfully installed. Then when I run command `antlr4`, I am getting message:

```
Could not get latest version number, attempting to fall back to latest downloaded version...
Found version '4.9.3', this version may be out of date
Could not find antlr4-4.9.3-complete.jar at maven.org
```

Does anybody know where could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: If you use Maven why not using antlr4-maven-plugin instead ?

Comment: I have seen these problems in the CI builds for https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 with Maven Central, especially with MacOS. Many timeouts. Remove the `~/.m2` directory, then manually redo the `antlr4` command with the `-v 4.13.1` option. Keep trying until you get the 4.13.1. Once you have it, do not remove the `~/.m2` directory since it is the cache for the Antlr tool jar.